# Enviar objeto con data-attributes Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json, javascript-objeto, data-atributos

Estoy utilizando data attributes para pasar información de un foreach de una función a otra, pero tengo un problema, el objeto está bien estructurado porque lo estoy usando en la otra función, pero cuando intento recibirlo del otro lado me da un error que normalmente aplica cuando se utilizan comillas simples '' en lugar de comillas dobles "", pero como dije ese no es mi caso pues la data ya la estoy usando de manera correcta del otro lado.

Acá estoy guardando los datos en un atributo data-info:

```
<div
  class="body-element"
  id="code${data.client_Id}"
  data-info="${JSON.stringify(data)}"
>
  <p class="text-element">
    <b class="id-b" id="client${data.client_Id}">${data.client_Id}</b
    ><span class="name-b" id="nameClient">${data.name}</span
    ><span class="dpi-b" id="dpiClient">${data.nationalId}</span
    ><span class="tel-b" id="phoneClient">${data.phone}</span>
  </p>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button
      class="btn dropdown-toggle"
      type="button"
      data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
      aria-expanded="false"
    ></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Acá lo estoy recibiendo:

```
let info = document.querySelector(".body-element");
var array = JSON.parse(info.dataset.info);
console.log(array);
```

Y este es el error que obtengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar al menos parte del contenido de tu JSON?

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que el HTML no se está formando correctamente. En este fragmento de código, el resultado de `JSON.stringify(data)` es:

```
{"name":"Cualquier nombre","age":27}
```

Al asignar esa cadena como valor entre comillas dobles queda algo así:

```
data-info="{"name":"Cualquier nombre","age":27}"
```

Pero el valor se corta al encontrar la primera comilla doble, guardando solo la llave de apertura. Dependiendo de los datos, podrías usar comillas simples para delimitar el valor:

```
data-info='{"name":"Cualquier nombre","age":27}'
```

Aunque lo ideal es no modificar directamente código HTML, sino crear elementos y agregarlos al contenedor deseado, que implica un poco más de trabajo, pero es "casi" a prueba de errores.

```js
let data = {
    name: 'Cualquier nombre',
    age: 27
};

// No se interpreta correctamente al crear el HTML como texto
document.body.innerHTML += `<div id="div1" data-info="${JSON.stringify(data)}">Texto dentro del div 1</div>`;

// En este sí funciona porque se evita usar comillas dobles para delimitar el valor
document.body.innerHTML += `<div id="div2" data-info='${JSON.stringify(data)}'>Texto dentro del div 2</div>`;


let div1 = document.querySelector('#div1');
console.log(div1.dataset.info); // Solo la llave de apertura

let div2 = document.querySelector('#div2');
console.log(div2.dataset.info); // Todo el objeto
```

Answer (score 0):

Opcional a la respuesta que ya te han dado lo que puedes hacer es escapar la comilla con su equivalente código en html:

```js
(function() {
  // reemplaza la comilla doble por su equivalente caracter escapado "&quot;" en HTML:
  var data = JSON.stringify([{ a: 1, b: 2 }]).replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
  var html = `<div data-info="${data}">Test</div>`;
  var main = document.querySelector('#main');
  main.innerHTML = html;

  const info = main.querySelector('div').dataset.info;
  const parsedData = JSON.parse(info);

  console.log(parsedData);
})();
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
```